# Are there any IDE's that support Python 3 syntax?

Tags: python, syntax, ide, python-3.x

I recently saw an announcement and [article](http://www.linux.com/feature/150399) outlining the release of the first [Python 3.0](http://www.python.org/download/releases/3.0/) release candidate. I was wondering whether there were any commercial, free, open source etc. IDE's that support its syntax.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python 3 is just **not that different** from Python 2.x.  In terms of syntax *per se*, things that will actually need to be handled differently by the parser, the only major change is in the replacement of the `print` statement with the `print` function.

Most of the features of Python can be easily probed via introspection (online help, method completion, function signatures, etc.), so there's no reason why any Python IDE will require major changes to work with Python 3.0.  I expect IDLE and SPE and the other open-source IDEs will be support it before the final release.

Comment: it depends how picky you want to be - there are enough differences, new/removed keywords, exception syntax, True , False , and None are now keywords, context's.

so while you can get away with python2 syntax for python3 code, its a valid question to ask for python3 support in an editor.

Answer (score 5):

Komodo 5 beta 1 was released in October 2008 and has initial support for Python 3 but I don't think I'd be using it for production code yet.

Given that Python 3 is still a very early release candidate, you may have some trouble finding mature support in IDEs.

Comment: I've used Komodo 5 with Python 3 code and it worked perfectly.

Comment: A lot may have changed since Oct 2008 when I answered this question - Python 3.0 is an ex-release and 3.1 is the latest. I'd be surprised if the support hadn't improved at least a little bit :-)

Comment: I'm using the latest Komodo IDE (5.2.2) and it still doesn't have anything close to decent Python 3 support. See for example the defect: http://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=79326

Answer (score 3):

[PyDev](http://pydev.org) for Eclipse does support 3.0.
You can configure multiple interpreters in the plug-in settings.

In the project properties you can set:

- Project type (Python, Jython, IronPython)
- Grammar version (2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4, 2.5, 2.6, 3.0).

*(PyDev version at time of writing: 1.4.7.)*

Answer (score 1):

Can get **PyDev.** from http://pydev.sourceforge.net. Its a plugin for Eclipse and is more than handy. Not to mention benefits of the old and trusted Eclipse.

Comment: Does pydev support python 3?  I couldn't find any info on this.

Answer (score 1):

Emacs + python.el continues to be better than anything else I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

[Pyscripter](http://code.google.com/p/pyscripter/) is the PERFECT Python IDE on windows; it's compatible even with the newly released Python 3.1.

Comment: Perfect is very subjective. ;)

Comment: Not perfect for me, but better than all the others I've tried.

Answer (score 1):

Geany works with python 3 if you install it and then:

> sudo gedit /usr/share/geany/filetypes.python

change the last 2 lines with:

compiler=python3 -c "import py_compile; py_compile.compile('%f')"

run_cmd=python3 "%f"

Answer (score 0):

I can say that at the time of posting this (Apr. 28 2009, version 0.8.4h) that [SPE](http://pythonide.blogspot.com/) does *not* correctly handle some python3 syntax - specifically exception handling. For example, the follow code is flagged as an error (and irritatingly, is jumped to whenever the file is saved):

```
except urllib.error.URLError as e:
        if hasattr(e, 'reason'):
        #...
```